Use of cartographer with IMU on Turtlebot 4
I try to use Cartographer on Turtlebot4. When I configure it without IMU, it starts to work, but the localization is not very good, and I sometimes lose connection with the robot.
When I enable IMU I got this error:
[cartographer_node-1] F1125 16:45:09.778687 37199 sensor_bridge.cpp:136] Check failed: sensor_to_tracking->translation().norm() < 1e-5 The IMU frame must be colocated with the tracking frame. Transforming linear acceleration into the tracking frame will otherwise be imprecise.
[cartographer_node-1] [FATAL] [1732553109.778919893] [cartographer logger]: F1125 16:45:09.000000 37199 sensor_bridge.cpp:136] Check failed: sensor_to_tracking->translation().norm() < 1e-5 The IMU frame must be colocated with the tracking frame. Transforming linear acceleration into the tracking frame will otherwise be imprecise.

Lua file:
include "map_builder.lua"
include "trajectory_builder.lua"

options = {
  map_builder = MAP_BUILDER,
  trajectory_builder = TRAJECTORY_BUILDER,
  map_frame = "map",
  tracking_frame = "base_footprint",
  published_frame = "odom",
  odom_frame = "odom",
  provide_odom_frame = false,
  publish_frame_projected_to_2d = true,
  use_odometry = true,
  use_nav_sat = false,
  use_landmarks = false,
  num_laser_scans = 1,
  num_multi_echo_laser_scans = 0,
  num_subdivisions_per_laser_scan = 1,
  num_point_clouds = 0,
  lookup_transform_timeout_sec = 0.2,
  submap_publish_period_sec = 0.3,
  pose_publish_period_sec = 5e-3,
  trajectory_publish_period_sec = 30e-3,
  rangefinder_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  odometry_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  fixed_frame_pose_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  imu_sampling_ratio = 1.,
  landmarks_sampling_ratio = 1.,
}

MAP_BUILDER.use_trajectory_builder_2d = true

TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.min_range = 0.12
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.max_range = 3.5
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.missing_data_ray_length = 3.0
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.use_imu_data = false
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.use_online_correlative_scan_matching = true 
TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.motion_filter.max_angle_radians = math.rad(0.1)

POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.min_score = 0.65
POSE_GRAPH.constraint_builder.global_localization_min_score = 0.7

POSE_GRAPH.optimize_every_n_nodes = 35

return options

